# bloomberg DDEinitiate via vba

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

the following is my code for sendkeys to bloomberg via vba.
option explicit
option base 1
sub DDETest()
dim blp as long
bpl = DDEInitiate("Winblp","bbk");
...
it didn't work when running to bpl = DDEInitiate("Winblp","bbk");

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a typo above. you have dim b**lp** as long, but b**pl** = ddeinitiate